# Hibernate 4.1 inside Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: hibernate, jsf, glassfish

I am trying to integrate the Hibernate framework into a web application running on Glassfish. However, I can't find any practical documentation or tutorials on the subject.

Can you please recommend some practical documentation in the subject?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes glassfish so different from other servers that you can't implement hibernate in your app? What problems are you facing? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, the question was asked when I was totally newbie. Now I am just newbie, so consider the question as irrelevant =) Thanks anyway!